# handling pet mice that bite

Tags: mice

I have recently bought 2 female mice, one of which is albino and quite small; I assume she is quite young. The other mouse is a regular size. Now my albino mouse (shiemi) is very easy to handle she will walk on my hand and let me hold her, sometimes she quietly avoids being picked up but she never bites. However, bourbon; my other mouse was a lot more timid. She would constantly hide in their den when I placed food or water in yet would take food from my hand and sniff me. However lately she has started to bite, I will place my hand stationary in their cage either palm up or down and each time she sniffed and then bit me. Is there any way I can make her more comfortable around me?

She doesn't always bite but is quite skittish, I held her once successfully for a few seconds but I didn't try today as I dont want to scare her too much.